# How to generate unique images from hashed informations with PHP GD?

Tags: php, hash, gd

Good day,

in the website I'm working on, I would like to display an unique image to the user generated with a
hash from his email address.

Should I generate fractals ?

If so, how can I make em "unique" or more specifically, easier to recognize by the user who has just
logged on ?

I pretty much like the associated user's images by Stackoverflow to their new users.

I am using PHP GD.

Thank in advance for any tips to achieve this.

Comment: This is exactly what gravatar.com does. Have you considered using them instead?

Comment: @Jonathan, That API is used to eventually use your personal avatar or something. I just want an image that a user will recognize being the "realwebsite" he is on. Displaying an image generated from his own email address (which should be unique in the system).

Comment: +1 As I'd love to see what implementations the community will come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some source code that you can run:
http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/unique_image

Sort of looks like the SOF image.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a name of that concept/ideas so I can find other examples?

Comment: @Cybrix, I've got no idea what that might be called, sorry. I struggled to name the function at the link above (I contributed it). Originally I thought maybe something like "hash_image" because it works almost like a hash function except you are generating colored polygons instead of characters.

Comment: @Cybrix They're called `Identicons`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have it done remotely, you could use something like http://robohash.org/ or gravatar http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/ (under the default section)

Comment: In particular, using the `identicon` parameter as the default option should do, e.g. http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d53?d=identicon Now let's just hope your calculated hash doesn't collide with the hash of someone's email address, otherwise you'd get their picture back ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you; it's a simple implementation using the image intervention library.

```
function unique_image($string, $img_w = 400)
{
    $hash = hash('md5', $string);
    $bytes = mb_strlen($hash, '8bit');
    $image = Image::canvas($img_w, $img_w, array_map('ord', str_split(substr($hash, -3, 3))));

    # Set color blocks.
    $blocks = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $bytes; $i++) $blocks[floor($i / 3)][] = ord($hash[$i]);

    $image_area = pow($img_w, 2);
    $square_area = $image_area / count($blocks);
    $sqr_w = sqrt($square_area);
    $cols = floor($img_w / $sqr_w);
    $spacing = ($img_w - $cols * $sqr_w) / 2;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $cols; $x++) for ($y = 0; $y < $cols; $y++) {
        $p['x1'] = $spacing + $sqr_w * $x;
        $p['y1'] = $spacing + $sqr_w * $y;
        $p['x2'] = $spacing + $sqr_w * ($x + 1);
        $p['y2'] = $spacing + $sqr_w * ($y + 1);

        $image->rectangle($p['x1'], $p['y1'], $p['x2'], $p['y2'], function ($draw) use ($x, $y, $blocks) {
            $block = $blocks[$x + $y];

            # Set square background (RGB), and the border.
            $draw->background([$block[0], ($block[1] ?? 0), ($block[2] ?? 0)]);
            $draw->border(1.8, '#aaa');
        });
    }

    # Return image.
    return $image->response();
}
```